# What is the reason for the "<nothing> not callable" mypy error?

Tags: python, mypy

UPDATE after 9 months: No error with `mypy` version 0.991. The issue was probably a problem in the `mypy` that has been fixed in the meantime.

---

Could you please explain why `mypy` complains about the last line of this demo program? I don't understand what is wrong. The program runs fine and prints the expected output.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Callable

class RevTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return super().__new__(cls, reversed(arg))

data = [1,3,5]

func: Callable[[Iterable], tuple]

func = tuple
print(func(data))

func = RevTuple
print(func(data))   # mypy: error: <nothing> not callable
```

Comment: what version of python are you using? in 3.8 the `RevTuple` at least works

Comment: @Nullman Python 3.10 and mypy 0.931

Comment: Seems to me a mypy bug or limit.